# Azure AD B2C Profile editing & native application

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

We use Azure AD B2C in a native mobile application. In our user account management blade we would like to use an Azure AD B2C profile editing policy. Is there a way to use an this kind of policy without having the sign-in process? We already have the `id_token`, can we way send it thru a parameter to prevent the user from having to sign-in once again?

Thanks in advance